# Csrf fix in node js at page level

Tags: html, node.js, csrf-protection, csrf-token

I looked at csrf implementation in node js [Git hub example](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) and was wondering this is for a application level. What if I want to apply it on one or two pages in the application. I did not find any example on the web. I know that in asp.net you can do it but not sure how the same can be achieved in Node JS.

Any help in guiding to a solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the csruf middleware on the routes which you want to protect. Like the [example](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#simple-express-example) in the Github link shows:

```
app.get('/route/to/protect', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
   // pass the csrfToken to the view
   res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})
```

This will allow csrf only for this route and not others. You can also use Regex to match routes as explained in the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: We are using res.redirect(). For this csrftoken cannot be passed the way you have shown in your example. Can you share a sample if we use res.redirect().